# Chrome: CSS properties with float values always have locale specific comma

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

first of all my finding/problem:

I get invalid css property values on setting float values in chrome dev tools.

```
document.body.style.left = "3.2323%"
```

The body applies the css code, but converts it to a locale string (I am living in Germany). All other major browsers do not seem to have this problem.

I found old posts on chrome version 6 and 19, where this kind of problem occured.

Anyone has an idea how to fix that or where to report this kind of problem?

Best regards

Michael

**edit 1:** Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be adding quotes to the values

Comment: What is your suggestion? This: document.body.style.left = 3.2323%

If yes, so you will receive syntax error

Comment: @j08691 All CSS values are strings in the JS API.

Comment: Can you clarify where you are seeing this? Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: added screenshot as edit 1

Answer (score 0):

Opened issue at chromium bugs. I saw 2 more guys having the same issue. If you found this question, there may be a solution for it in my ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=623347